# Background with different colored rows - css only

Tags: css

is it possible to create a background with rows which are different colored?

Here's some Pseudo-Code to illustrate it:

```
body {
    row-1 {
        height: 250px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    row-2 {
        height: 250px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    row-n {
        height: 250px;
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that in css only?

Comment: "element" `:nth-child(odd){background:red}`

Answer (score -2):

You can use gradient to achieve this. You can use a online css gradient generator. Here is [an example](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28255%5C%2C38%5C%2C0%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28255%5C%2C30%5C%2C0%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%2838%5C%2C0%5C%2C255%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%2838%5C%2C0%5C%2C255%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2076%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%280%5C%2C255%5C%2C0%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2076%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%280%5C%2C255%5C%2C0%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2090%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28238%5C%2C255%5C%2C0%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2090%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28238%5C%2C255%5C%2C0%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B').

EDIT: I think I misinterpreted your question. Are you just asking how to give different divs in your body different colors? either give them all distinctive classes so you can style each of them independently, or use `:nth-child(x)` where you replace `x` with the div number you want to style (e.g. if you want to style the second div, use `:nth-child(2)`

Comment: hmm, don't know if gradient is the proper tool. But thanks I'll lokk into it and no, no html, if possible css only. :)